# Crashlytics for iOS does logs crash only when app is opened after the crash

Tags: ios, crashlytics

In an iOS Mobile App why does crashlytics log crash and send email, when the iOS app is opened after the crash. This behavior is not consistent when crashlytics is integrated with android app. 
Typically after a crash, user will stop using the app and not open it again. As a consequence we end up missing several crashes which happen in iOS.

Comment: Kemani - It is expected behavior, you cant send any request to server if app is closed right ? Same limitation applied to Crash analytic.

Comment: What you say makes sense. However it is not consistent with Android. When the Android App crashes Crashlytic logs the crash immediately and I do not have to re-open the android app. Is there a setup issue for iOS which I am missing

Comment: Android uses backgroung sevices that allows app to send and receive request from server, so when your app is killed in android it will send your crash report.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. The behavior is different on each platform since each platform has different behaviors for exception handling and networking.

On iOS, it's unsafe to send much, if any, data after an exception happens that leads to a crash. The app is a horrible state and the device is also resolving an unexpected situation. If, we or other services, tried to send additional data then, you could run the risk of causing an issue on the entire device which it would require the device to restart. Asking a user to restart their device is a much worse behavior then having them need to relaunch the app.

You are correct that some users may never relaunch the app and those crashes are lost, but in general, we've found most users relaunch the app post-crash.

As @Dev_Tandel said, on Android, other background networking services can be used to try and send the crash report then. We will try to do that, but don't guarantee that a report will be sent until the app is relaunched.